# Как запускать поток каждые 15 секунд используя ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: android, android-threads

Нужно, чтобы поток запускался сново через каждые 15 секунд. Для запуска использовала ScheduledExecutorService. Но поток запускается не через каждые 15 секунд, а через большие промежутки времени.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.d("myLogs", "Yes!");
                    for(int i = 0; i < 270; i++) {
                        final Response response =  requestInterface.getCard().execute();
                        if (response.code() == 200) {
                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    items.add((Card)response.body());
                                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


02-06 07:49:49.986 2062-2080/? D/myLogs: Yes!
02-06 07:51:50.151 2062-2080/? D/myLogs: Yes!
02-06 07:53:55.283 2062-2080/? D/myLogs: Yes!
```

Comment: >>Но поток запускается не через каждые 15 секунд, а через большие промежутки времени.<< Вопрос, эти промежутки больше 15 секунд? Всё логично, скорее всего, команда говорит не "каждые 15 секунд", а "не ранее чем через 15 секунд". В этом вся соль большинства очередей и потоков.

Comment: test123, а какая команда будет говорить "каждые 15 секунд"?

Comment: + В теле потока вы не передаёте управления другим потокам. Тот кто первый захватит процессор, тот и будет крутить вашу программу, остальные будут ждать в сторонке своей очереди. Если хотите параллельное выполнение, делайте Thread.Sleep либо аналоги передачи управления другим потокам внутри вашего цикла

Comment: >>а какая команда будет говорить "каждые 15 секунд"<< очевидно, вечный цикл с ожиданием в 15 секунд - это будет наиболее точный механизм в плане "каждые n единиц времени", остальные варианты будут пытаться приблизиться к определённому интервалу. Так же, есть ещё такая замечательная вещь как таймеры.

Comment: О вечных циклах даже не думайте :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, >>О вечных циклах даже не думайте<< ИМХО, только такой примитивный способ наглядно показывает как реализуются таймеры и обработчики очередей/пула потоков. Использовать не рекомендую, но, и не знать - не советую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `scheduleWithFixedDelay` запускает ваше задание через 15 секунд после завершения предыдущего. Отсюда и такие интервалы.

Если вам надо стартовать каждые 15 секунд вне зависимости от состояния предыдущего задания, используйте `scheduleAtFixedRate`.

**НО!**
У вас только один тред в пуле.

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

Поэтому все равно executor будет ждать освобождения треда.
Или увеличьте кол-во тредов в пуле (!!!) или продумайте хорошо расписание.

Comment: Eugene Krivenja,  если метод scheduleWithFixedDelay поменять на метод scheduleAtFixedRate и изменить количество тредов в пуле (например, на 2, 3, 5 или любое количество), то поток запускается также редко (раз в две минуты).  02-06 08:38:48.786 2704-2731/? D/myLogs: Yes!
02-06 08:40:44.081 2704-2731/? D/myLogs: Yes!

Comment: Возможно у вас пул весь занят. Смотрите как именно первые запуски происходят (первые Х, где Х - количество тредов в пуле).

Comment: Советую вам пересмотреть ваш код, 270 раз вызывать в цикле какой-то интерфейс и при этом обновлять UI, как-то это все очень неоптимально выглядит. Если предположить, что 270 итераций за 15 секунд -> 18 обновлений recyclerView за секунду !!!

Comment: Eugene Krivenja, может сначала запросом данные загружать в SQLite, а уже оттуда выгружать в recycle view? Как вариант решения проблемы

Comment: @Anna13, ИМХО, по тому что я могу видеть, вам нужен промис, либо каллбек, а не циклы. Откуда ждать результата - сеть или БД - не имеет значения. Просто у вас своеобразная попытка отображать состояние, учитывая как яро вы спамите интерфейс запросами... Однако, всё это не относится к вопросу о том, как запускать задачу каждые 15 секунд., как и бессмысленный спор с Eugene Krivenja

Comment: Наилучшее решение, получать объекты `Card` все сразу и обновлять UI один раз. Через базу данных или нет, это уже детали.

Answer (score -1):

Положим, что ваша функция, которую надо делать раз в 15 секунд имеет вид:

```
private void yourFunction(){
    try {
        Log.d("myLogs", "Yes!");
        for(int i = 0; i < 270; i++) {
            final Response response =  requestInterface.getCard().execute();
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        items.add((Card)response.body());
                        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100L);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

1. Примитивный способ вызывать её раз в 15 сек:

   ```
   for(;;) {
       new Thread(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run(){
               yourFunction();
           }
       }).start(); // при условии что запуск потока будет достаточно быстрым
       Thread.Sleep(15*1000);
   }
   ```
2. Высокоуровневый способ, [основанный на таймере](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) (вызывает функцию раз в 15 секунд):

   ```
   Timer timer = new Timer();
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
       @Override
       public void run(){
           yourFunction();
       }
   },0,15*1000);
   ```

Comment: А теперь представьте, ваш код исполняется и запускает каждые 15 секунд задание, которое длится 45 секунд. Что произойдет рано или поздно? :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, ну, представил, и к чему это? Можно много всего придумать... Представим что у ТС WinPhone. Как к вопросу то относится? Эту же проблему не решит пул на 9999 задач. Почему вы это не представили?

Comment: Автор пошла верным путем, thread executors для того и существуют, чтобы не писали вечных циклов и не стреляли себе в ногу созданием 100500 потоков.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, Вы не пояснили, что мешает ТС разрешить 100500 активных потоков в очереди?

Comment: Мешают злые пользователи приложения, которое жрет батарею, сетевой трафик, тормозит и в конце концов падает.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, Ничего не понял... у нас есть Таймер, который вам не нравится, и есть Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100500), их обоих я считаю эквивалентными по Эскобару. Что конкретно вы считаете плохим решением?