# Очередь из HTTP запросов

Tags: android, http, запрос, okhttp

Доброго времени суток.

Есть такой код:

```
public void maintain_connection(final String url) {
    final String ur = url;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        busy = true;
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url(ur)
                                .build();

                        client.newCall(request)
                                .enqueue(new Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(final Call call, final IOException e) {

                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                //Toast.makeText(c, "Ошибка...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                busy = false;
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                                        final String res = response.body().string();
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                //Toast.makeText(c, "Мы отправили запрос!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                busy = false;
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 500); //execute in every 50000 ms
}

public void doRequest(String url){
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request)
            .enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(final Call call, final IOException e) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(c, String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                    final String res = response.body().string();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           // Toast.makeText(c, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

Он отправляет каждые 500 м/с запрос на сервер.

Сервер, куда это всё отправляется - однопоточный.

Суть в чём:

Если в тот момент, когда мы поддерживаем подключение с сервером (отправляем запрос на сервер) нажать на кнопку, которая будет вызывать метод doRequest -

выполняется лишь запрос, который поддерживает подключение с сервером.

Получается так, что выполняется старный запрос и тут же начинает выполнятся новый, но сервер, так как он однопоточный, обрабатывает лишь один запрос в секунду, грубо говоря.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы если мы в данный момент отправляем запрос (любой, хоть поддержания подключения, хоть тот, который будет отправлен по нажатию кнопки) - они как-бы становились в очередь друг за другом?

Проще говоря, чтобы ничего не "провисало", а работало нормально, и обрабатывало оба запроса?

Помогите, пожалуйста. Уже 2 дня мучаюсь...

Comment: Для начала переделайте HTTP запросы в синхронные (без Callback), а потом отправляйте эти задачи (Runnable) в singleTheadExecutor, они там по очереди и будут исполнятся. Потому что сейчас у вас на один Runnable происходит цепочка асинхронных запросов и никакого контроля над этим.

Comment: Для инспирации: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780928/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B5-15-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-scheduledexecutorservice

Comment: плюсую первый ответ Евгения, но в целом проблему это не решит. Это натуральная заплатка. Исправляйте сервер, т.к. с 1 потоком - это совершенно не рабочая структура. Как только вы выпустите релиз, все сойдется в узком месте.

Comment: заниматься такими вещами на клиенте - извращение (IMHO), не проще серверную часть доработать нормально и там организовать такую очередь, если уж вам необходимо последовательно обрабатывать запросы сервером... вообще трудно в настоящее время представить http сервер, который работает в однопоточном режиме, обычно один connection - свой поток, но в вопросе недостаточно информации об архитектуре всей системы в целом.

Comment: @mit, серверная часть, если уж на то пошло, - ESP 12-e (Node MCU), которая отправляет информацию на Arduino. Там просто невозможно сделать больше, чем 1 поток